# Filter rows based on the dplyr groupby, summarize output

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with two columns, metro, state. I give the following command in dplyr,

```
data %>% group_by(metro, State) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

I get the following output,

```
metro           State         count 
A                OH            703
A                NJ              3
B                GA           1453
B                CA            456
B                WA            123
```

I now want to filter out the rows in the dataframe which are only the maximum counts and leave out the remaining. I need to filter out the corresponding rows. The output after filtering out the rows for the following command should be,

```
data %>% group_by(metro, State) %>% summarise(count = n())

   metro           State         count 
    A                OH            703
    B                GA           1453
```

Where every metro has only state which is the state with maximum counts and remaining are removed.

The following is my trying,

```
data %>% group_by(metro, State) %>% filter(n() == max(n()))
```

But this is again giving out the same dataframe as input.

Can anybody help me in doing this? My output should be every metro should have a unique state which has the maximum counts and the remaining state entries should be removed.

Thanks

Comment: `data %>% group_by(metro) %>% filter(count == max(count))`

Comment: @Psidom This still gives me the same output because when we group by metro, the count adds up and we can't filter out maximum entries.

Comment: @Psidom I am able to filter out after summarizing.. My question is to filter out the original dataframe with the corresponding rows. If previously the dataframe had 2738 rows, I need it to have 2156 rows only after filtering. THe rows corresponding to (3, 456, 123) counts should be removed .

Comment: Please add a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a double stage groupby, firstly groupby metro and state get the count and then groupby metro and filter out count that is not equal to the max count within each metro:

```
data1 <- data %>% group_by(metro, State) %>% mutate(count = n()) %>% 
                  group_by(metro) %>% filter(count == max(count))

nrow(data1)
```

Comment: I am not sure why you get different results. But this seems to be working for me. Is this what you need?

Comment: This is not the requirement of my question. I have given my explanation in the comment. I want to remove the corresponding rows in the data frame. Not the summarized rows.

Comment: I am able to filter out after summarizing.. My question is to filter out the original dataframe with the corresponding rows. If previously the dataframe had 2738 rows, I need it to have 2156 rows only after filtering. THe rows corresponding to (3, 456, 123) counts should be removed .

Comment: Doesn't this give me only the counts ? My question here is I want to filter the entire original dataframe with the number of rows. Not the counts.

Comment: I think you should try the answer first. It will still give you the whole data frame just with a few rows filtered out.

Comment: I tried this. But I am getting the same dataframe as output with the same number of rows.

Comment: I can't argue with you about this any more. Please paste your original data frame so that we can make it reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,  count := .N , .(metro, state)][,  .SD[count == max(count)] , .(metro)]
```